# Android AsyncTask as NOT an Inner class : Weird NullPointerException

Tags: android, soap, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, ksoap2

This question is reproduced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148461/android-nullpointerexception-what-could-be-null-here), the code given is a minimalistic example of the problem. In this example, we are consuming the [temperature conversion SOAP web service of w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx), using `ksoap2` library:

**The problem is that I get a NullPointerException on `ed = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_editText1);` in MyTask. 
I know I can implement the AsyncTask as an inner class but I read that it can be implemented as a separate class, so why this problem.**

This application has a main activity named `MainActivity`. The `MainActivity` has an onclick-listener method, inside which another activity by the name of `SecondActivity` is started.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void StartSecondActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then there is a separate `AsyncTask` class called `MyTask`. We provide a constructor of `MyTask` for assigning an activity (an instance of `MainActivity` here) passed to it to an activity object we are creating inside `MyTask` called `mainActivity`, the reason for which is to invoke Activity's method `findViewById`.

From the `SecondActivity`, we create an object of `MyTask` using that constructor and passing to it an instance of the main activity in our app; and then call execute on that `MyTask` object.

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        new MyTask(new MainActivity()).execute();
    }
}
```

Now inside `MyTask`, I am reading an `EditText` from the main activity. Then using it as a celsius value and adding it to the SOAP request to call the web service. Then in the end I am displaying the result from the web service in a `TextView` in the `SecondActivity` in `onPostExecute`.

**MyTask.java:**

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    Activity mainActivity;
    EditText ed;
    TextView tv;
    String searchString;

    private static final String TAG = MyTask.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    public static final String METHOD_NAME ="CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    public static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";

    MyTask(Activity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (mainActivity!=null) {
            ed = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_editText1);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "mainActivity is null.");
        }
        searchString = ed.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SoapObject requestSoapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        requestSoapObject.addProperty("Celsius", searchString);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestSoapObject);

        HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapPrimitive webServiceResultSoapPrimitive = null;
        try {
            htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            webServiceResultSoapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return webServiceResultSoapPrimitive.toString();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute (String webServiceResultString) {
        System.out.println("Sysout : " + webServiceResultString);
        tv = (TextView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.secondActivity_textView1); 
        tv.setText("Fahrenheit : " + webServiceResultString);
    }

}
```

Comment: `new MainActivity()`? That's not how it works.

Comment: @PedroOliveira ? Don't we create an object of a class like this? Can you tell me the right way then?

Comment: Is that why you are giving a downvote? Because I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to do here. But putting things simple...there can only be one activity visible at the time... So the fact that you're doing `new MainActivity()` doesn't mean you're creating a new activity...let alone using the first activity.

Comment: @PedroOliveira I am not at all trying to create a activity screen, I am just creating an instance of the `MainActivity` class and passing it to the constructor of `MyTask` because you can see that the constructor takes an `Activity` as a parameter.

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. There is too much wrong in this code right now. I don't even know where to start :\

Comment: @PedroOliveira Why do I need this instance of `Activity` in `MyTask`? Because I am invoking the `findViewById` method of the `Activity` class twice in `MyTask`.

Comment: I know @Zarah but that's not how you should do it. Check codeMagic's answer.

Comment: Who said the downvote is mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410697/pedro-oliveira) stated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152097/android-asynctask-as-not-an-inner-class-weird-nullpointerexception#comment42798740_27152097) you don't want to try and instantiate an `Activity` the way you are.

All you need to do is to pass the value from the first to second `Activity`. Then you can pass that value to the constructor of your `AsyncTask`.

So, in your `onClick()` of the first `Activity` you pass it as an `Extra`.

```
public void StartSecondActivity(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_editText1);
    String temp = et.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("temp", temp);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

then retrieve it and pass it to the task

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // get the String
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String temp = i.getStringExtra("temp");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        // and pass it here
        new MyTask(temp).execute();
    }
}
```

now get it in your task

```
MyTask(String value) {
    searchString= value; 
}
```

Comment: For this part, thank you so very much. I surely should have done this way. Now, still I am calling `findViewById` in `onPostexecute`, what do I do there?

Comment: What are you doing? Calling the 2nd activity just to run the task then pass the value back to the first activity? I don't see the point in the second activity

Comment: No, the TextView where I am displaying the result is in the second activity. OK, trying to call `findViewByActivity` to find a view of second activity *using an object of the first activity* is a clear mistake now, but still I need to display the result in the second activity.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) on using an `interface` to update the activity. You also can instantiate the `TextView` in your second activity and pass a reference to the task